# python using pyshark to parse .pcap file

Tags: python, pyshark

I have a wireshark .pcap file and i want to get all the assets (urls, ip's, pc names etc..) from this file.
i tried to use some examples i found online, but i'm having some problems getting those items.
i managed to find the dst and src ip address, but thats all.

this is my current code:

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture('dor.pcap')

count = 0
for pkt in cap:
    ip_source = pkt.ip.__dict__["_all_fields"]["ip.src"]
    ip_address = pkt.ip.__dict__["_all_fields"]["ip.dst"]
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the assets info?  What should the output look like?

Answer (score 2):

This should work with your *Wireshark* pcap file to obtain the source and destination addresses and ports.  The output could be modified (e.g., csv, dictionary) to fit your specific requirements.

*Please provide **more details** on the other items that you would like to parse from a pcap file.*

```
import pyshark

def network_conversation(packet):
  try:
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    source_address = packet.ip.src
    source_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    destination_address = packet.ip.dst
    destination_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
    return (f'{protocol} {source_address}:{source_port} --> {destination_address}:{destination_port}')
  except AttributeError as e:
    pass

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('test.pcap')
conversations = []
for packet in capture:
  results = network_conversation(packet)
  if results != None:
    conversations.append(results)

# this sorts the conversations by protocol 
# TCP and UDP
for item in sorted(conversations):
  print (item)
```

Comment: This code is working exactly it is supposed to,